# How to control the ticklabel size in TikZ graphics?

Tags: pgfplots, matlab2tikz, ticks

Is there any method to control the size of ticklabels in LaTeX when using `pgfplots`? It seems that the yticks are written in a wrong way

[image]

LaTeX snippet:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
unbounded coords=jump,
scale only axis,
xmin=0.6,
xmax=11.4,
xtick={1,3,5,7,9,11},
xticklabels={1e-1,1e0,1e1,1e2,1e3,1e4},
x tick label style={rotate=45, anchor=east, align=center},
xlabel={$\lambda$1},
xmajorgrids,
y dir=reverse,
ymin=0,
ymax=12,
ytick={0.1,2.5,5,7.5,10,12},
yticklabels={1e-1,1,1e1,1e2,1e3,1e4},
ylabel={$\lambda$2},
ymajorgrids,
zmin=0,
zmax=2,
zlabel={rmse endmember},
zmajorgrids,
name=plot6,
title={MVC},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
axis z line*=left
]
\addplot3[%
surf,
shader=faceted,
draw=black,
......]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

Comment: Complete examples are always better than snippets. I don't know exactly what's happened, but if changing the font size is enough you can try something like `ticklabel style={font=\tiny}` added to the `axis` options.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ticklabel style={font=\tiny},`. You can use any font size here. The ytick labels are dispalyed properly for me so I can't do much. May be you have to provide complete code as suggested by Torbjorn.

```
\documentclass{Article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
%width=\figurewidth,
%height=\figureheight,
unbounded coords=jump,
scale only axis,
xmin=0.6,
xmax=11.4,
xtick={1,3,5,7,9,11},
xticklabels={1e-1,1e0,1e1,1e2,1e3,1e4},
x tick label style={rotate=45, anchor=east, align=center},
xlabel={$\lambda$1},
xmajorgrids,
y dir=reverse,
ymin=0,
ymax=12,
ytick={0.1,2.5,5,7.5,10,12},
yticklabels={1e-1,1,1e1,1e2,1e3,1e4},
ylabel={$\lambda$2},
ymajorgrids,
zmin=0,
zmax=2,
zlabel={rmse endmember},
zmajorgrids,
name=plot6,
title={MVC},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
axis z line*=left,
ticklabel style={font=\tiny},
]
\addplot3[%
surf,
shader=faceted,
draw=black,samples=50
]
{1/(2*sqrt(pi*y)) * exp(0-x^2/y)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]